# YouTube Quota Limit by IP address or Key?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Are the quota limits set for the YouTube API key specific or by IP address that is requesting the data?  For example, if my quota limit is 100 searches per day, is that 100 per API key or 100 per user using the application making the request?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which request are you making exactly. Most of them are project based.  Only the flood protection ones are user based.

Comment: It is for the search API.  I was afraid it was project-based.  I really only need to search for the top result from a term query.  The problem is, I want to be able to show the top video result for a list of 300 different term queries.

Answer (score 1):

Every api has a specific quota. You can view them here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/

Each api doc has  `Quota impact`. for "search:list"

Quota impact: A call to this method has a [quota cost](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota) of 100 units.

> Projects that enable the YouTube Data API (this is for entire youtube API) have a default quota
> allocation of 10,000 units per day, an amount sufficient for the
> overwhelming majority of our API users.

It says projects which mean API keys. Since there is a quota limit, it is a good practice to get some data for development and testing and keep it in the JSON data. Use your quota for the production